# Change UITableView Background Color for all pages

Tags: ios, uitableview

Now, I can change UITableView Background color like

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
  [self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]];
  [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tblbg.png"]]];
}
```

But I need to add codes in all of the files. I don't want to create UITableView sub class.

Is it possible to make category for UITableView to change background color ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an easy enough thing to try out?

UITableView+CustomBackgroundColor.h:

```
@interface UITableView (CustomBackgroundColor)

@end
```

UITableView+CustomBackgroundColor.m:

```
@implementation UITableView (CustomBackgroundColor)

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tblbg.png"]]];
}

@end
```